# Find the value of this infinitely nested radical (it appears to obtain multiple values)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, radicals, nested-radicals

> Find the value of $$\sqrt{1-\sqrt{\frac{17}{16}-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{\frac{17}{16}-\cdots}}}}$$

This is not as simple as it looks for one reason - there are $2$ real solutions to the equation $$x=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{\frac{17}{16}-x}}\implies\begin{cases}x_1=0.5\\x_2\approx 0.073\end{cases}$$

You can see that for yourself [on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+sqrt+%7B+1-+sqrt%7B17%2F16-x%7D+%7D).

How can we know the real value of this infinite radical?

Comment: I suggest you iterate the nested radicals and see to wich of the two values it converges...

Comment: What do we mean by "the value"?  One approach would be to consider the sequence obtained by truncating the expression at successive levels.  The first term, $\sqrt{1}$, seems clear, but the second term would be problematic, the square root of a negative number.  So it suggests the sequence at best has one or more convergent subsequences.

Comment: The most intuitive way to see it, I think, is to construct the [cobweb diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) for the iterations of this function. You'll see that only one of the roots is an attractor.

Comment: @Semiclassical How could I construct it, though? I mean, it would take a lot of time, maybe there's a website that would help me out..

Comment: By hand is the simplest way, in imitation of the Wikipedia page's animation. (Not sure what a good computer program for it is.) You don't need to do a lot of iterations to get the sense of it, either.

Comment: Looking at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqrt%281-sqrt%2817%2F16-x%29%29%3Dx%2C+range+0+to+0.6 it seems clear that $1/2$ is the attractive fixed point.

Comment: @VincentPfenninger The graph of $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{\frac{17}{16}-x}}$ may look a bit more tending to be closer to the value $0.5$, but not sure how this tells us anything. The graphs intersect at both points.

Comment: How do you know that this will be real when evaluated? There are square-roots of potentially negative numbers here

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Don't ignore the link to Wolfram Alpha that is provided. It's great that you took your time to write out a solution manually, but it was not what I was asking for, the Wolfram Alpha already showed us all the possible solutions, and they are all real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{\frac{17}{16}-x}}$ on $\left[\frac1{16},\frac{17}{16}\right]$:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

$f$ is monotonically increasing on $\left[\frac1{16},\frac{17}{16}\right]$. To be precise,
$$
f'(x)=\frac1{4f(x)\left(1-f(x)^2\right)}\tag{1}
$$

$B$, $C=\!\!\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$, and $D=\!\!\left(\frac{17}{16},1\right)$ are the points where $f(x)=\frac89x+\frac1{18}$.

$A$ and $C$ are the points where $f(x)=x$.

Evaluating $f'$ at the two roots of $f(x)=x$, we get
$$
f'(A_x)\doteq3.4345\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
f'\left(\frac12\right)=\frac23\tag{3}
$$
This means that $A$ is an unstable fixed point of $f$ and $C$ is a stable fixed point of $f$. In fact, for $x\in\left[B_x,D_x\right]$, we have
$$
\frac23\le\frac{f(x)-\frac12}{x-\frac12}\le\frac89\tag{4}
$$
Furthermore, for $x\in\left(\frac1{16},B_x\right]$,
$$
f'(x)\gt\frac53\tag{5}
$$
$(4)$ and $(5)$ say that

1. if $x_0\in\left(A_x,\frac{17}{16}\right]$, then $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ will converge to $\frac12$.
2. if $x_0=A_x$, then $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ is the constant sequence $x_n=A_x$.
3. if $x_0\in\left[\frac1{16},A_x\right)$, then $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ will get smaller until at some point $x_n\lt\frac1{16}$.

where $A_x\doteq0.073182744516454277369$.

Comment: The functions $a(x):=\sqrt{1-x}$ and $b(x):=\sqrt{{17\over16}-x}$ are at stake. We know that $a$ is applied last, but we don't know which one was applied first. If $a$ is applied first we should make sure that $x_0<0.994644$, so that $x_1>A_x$, whereupon your analysis works.

Comment: True. We simply need to map the points $\frac1{16}$, $0.073182744516454277369$, and $\frac{17}{16}$ to $\frac{255}{256}$, $0.994644285905039381396$, and $-\frac{33}{256}$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution technique:

Let 
$$L = \sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{6} - \sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{6} -\sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{16} -... } } } }} } $$

The natural method of solution is to observe that

$$L^2 = 1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{6} - \sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{6} -\sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{16} -... } } } }}$$

So...

$$ L^2  - 1= -\sqrt{\frac{17}{16} - \sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{16} -\sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{16} -... } } } }}$$

Therefore

$$ (L^2 - 1)^2 = \frac{17}{16} - \sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{16} -\sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{16} -... } } } }$$

Implying:

$$(L^2 - 1)^2 - \frac{17}{16} = -\sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{16} -\sqrt{1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{16} -... } } } }$$

And therefore we substitute

$$(L^2 - 1)^2 - \frac{17}{16} = -L$$

Now this equation has 4 possible solutions each expression for $L$ behaves algebraically the same as this nested radical.

The reason is because if you recall from algebra there are two possible $\sqrt{x}$ for any number (a positive and negative root). Now we need to de-nest 2 roots before we can exploit our substitution so what ends up happening is that that are really four possible infinite-radicals (depending on the types of roots we alernated with) that could've yielded this $L$. Your job is to then approximate YOUR problem to a good amount and see which of the 4 solutions to

$$(L^2 - 1)^2 - \frac{17}{16} = -L$$

Corresponds and even then, we may have more than one converging value if our nested radical trends in a way analogous to

$$1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1...$$

Whose sum can be seen as 1 or 0 depending on how one chooses to enumerate its values.

Comment: Not sure if this answers my question. I already gave the $2$ possible real values of $x$, so $2$ solutions of your equation don't work for sure, but my question was which of the values $0.5$ and $\approx 0.073$ the infinite radical is equal to, not how to get the few possible values manually, Wolfram Alpha already told me the possibilities. You've suggested to try approximating my radical enough to see which works, but this has already been suggested in the comments.

Comment: This is a very subtle problem if you do not want to approximate it. You need to view the answer, pre simplified, when plugged into the Quartic Formula. At that point you will be able to choose unit-coefficients (the way there is a + and - choice in the quadratic formula). I don't know which of the four roots of unity (1,-1,i,-i) is the right one to pick to yield your answer but perhaps someone with better intuition would know. I believe that the unit 1 is ruled out (that corresponds to $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{...}}$) and so is $i$ and $-i$ (my guess is they yield complex answers) so (-1) seems right

Comment: The $\frac{17}{6}$ in your answer should be $\frac{17}{16}$

Answer (score 1):

Let's study the following sequel: $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$. Here, $f(u_n)= \sqrt{ 1 - \sqrt{\frac{17}{16}-u_n}}$.

1/ Where is it defined? Well, necessarily $u_n\leq\frac{17}{16}$ and $u_n\geq\frac{17}{16}-1 = \frac{1}{16}$.

2/ What intervals are stable by $f$? Well looking at $f$ pretty much its entire domain: $f([0,\frac{17}{16}])\subset [0,\frac{17}{16}]$

3/ What are the possible fixed points? As you've noted, there are 2 solutions, x=0.5 and $x=0.0731...$

4/ Checking that the points are attractive / repulsive. Basically, you're checking if $|u_{n+2} - u_{n+1}|=|f(u_{n+1}) - f(u_n)| < K |u_{n+1} - u_{n}|$, that is if $f-Id$ is K-lipschitz with K<1. To make things easy, you simply look at your derivative and take the sup on the relevant interval.

What you find is that $|f-Id|'_{x=0.0783} =2.43$: this point is going to repulse the sequel. On the other hand, $|f-Id|'_{x=0.5} =0.33..$ and will be attractive.

5/ In conclusion, either you start with $u_0 = 0.0783$ and $u_n = u_0=0.0783$ or $u_0 \not = 0.0783$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} u_n = 0.5$.

If you want to be really clean, you need a proper study of what intervals are stable by $f$, and take the sup on those, showing that the rest of the domain will bring you there.